# Google search CSE not working: Refused to display in a frame because it set x-frame-options to sameorigin

Tags: search, joomla, google-search-api

I'm working in a Joomla 1.5 website and there is a Google search (CSE) module; the problem is that no results appear after a search. I discovered that this happens due to the error:

> refused to display in a frame because it set 'x-frame-options' to 'sameorigin'

I've done a lot of research but I still can't find any solution to this. The modules and components are updated in Joomla. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after days of researching, I finally came to terms that it wouldn't work, Google does not support iframes anymore (at least for the searchs) so I decided to do the following:

1 - Use the tool provided by Google on www.google.com/cse and get the code provided by them. I used the layout "Overlay" as I could only use one place to add the entire code.

2 - Created a HTML module in Joomla and pasted the code provided by Google.

3 - I had to so styling so I did it using document.getElementById inside the script that Google provided.

I'm not sure I should add a [Solved] to my question title as the original problem wasn't solved.

Well, thanks everybody! =)